# $\int_0^1 (f(x))^n =$ constant, $f\geq 0$, then $f$ is a characteristic function of a measurable set.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

$\int_0^1 (f(x))^n =$ constant, $f\geq 0$, then $f$ is a characteristic function of a measurable set. This is the result from question part (a).

Now for part (b), will it also hold when the assumption $f\geq0$ is removed?

Here are my thoughts. Since the result from part (a) holds for $f^2 \geq 0$, then $f^2$ is a characteristic function of a measurable set. Now if $f$ takes the value $-1$ on a set of positive measure, $\int_0^1 (f(x))^n$ would not be constant for even and odd $n$.

Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: If you allow $f$ to take complex values, $f(x)=e^{2\pi ix}$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

You could also use that

$$\int f^2 - f =0$$

by assumption, but (because $f^2$ is a characteristic function so that $f$ is of modulus one) $f^2 - f = |f|-f\geq 0$, which yields $|f| = f$ a.e., so that you can apply (a).